# Change date format "Authored on" for views with replacement pattern

Tags: 8, datetime

In Druapl 8, how can i change the date format used in a view (see screen shot)

[image]

The view uses a replacement pattern `{{ created }} == Authored on`

and i don’t find where to modify the format. I’ve checked :

> configuration / regional and language / date and time formats

But i don’t know how to use the custom format with {{ created }} in the view.

Could it be done in admin without modify template file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 8, fields use the normal field formatters.  In your list of Fields in the View, click on **Content: Authored on (Authored on)**.  You can change the **Formatter** to what you want (same choices as **Manage Display** on the content type configuration).  You can then configure other options, like the format.

If you already are using `{{ created }}` in the template, and you need it in a different format for a replacement pattern / token, then add **Content: Authored on (Authored on)** again to the list of **Fields**, but exclude it from display.  Reorder things, so this appears before the field you need it as a token.  Configure it as above.  Then, where you need the token, you should have `{{ created_1 }}`, which is the duplicate you just made.

Comment: Thanks, it was simple but i was not familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

I havent try, but if you can use some twig maybe with something like that:

```
{{created|format_date("name_of_your_format")}}
```

Or

```
{{created.value|format_date("name_of_your_format")}}
```

maybe try to inspect that 'created' variable with a `{{dump(created)}}`
Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want a solution that involves replacement patterns, I've found that you need to use the raw value and run it through a conversion to UNIX time if you want to use a Drupal date format.

For example, I have a view of media that have an "Imported date" field (`field_date_imported`):

```
{{ field_date_imported__value | date("U") | format_date("medium") }}
```

I'm using this to add a "title" attribute to a span wrapping a "Time ago" date, so that the user can hover over the date to get the actual timestamp.